How can I avoid unnecessary memory allocation when mapping lists of Python datetime.date objects to a C++ std::vector of dates using SWIG?
I am trying to interface a C++ library with Python using SWIG 4.2. At the moment I am trying to write typemaps to convert Python datetime.date objects to and from a C++ Date class, which is based on the std::chrono::time_point<>. In particular I am trying to allow a user to pass a Python list of datetime.date to as a std::vector<Date>.
Initially I started by defining simple in/out typemaps for the Date class as follows:
%inline %{
#include "Common/Date/Date.h"
#include <datetime.h>
%}

%init %{
    PyDateTime_IMPORT;
%}

%typemap(in) Date {
    auto year_month_day((std::chrono::year_month_day(std::chrono::year(PyDateTime_GET_YEAR($input)), std::chrono::month(PyDateTime_GET_MONTH($input)), std::chrono::day(PyDateTime_GET_DAY($input)))));
    $1 = DATE::Date(std::chrono::sys_days(year_month_day));
}

%typemap(out) Date {
    auto year_month_day($1.year_month_day());
    $result = PyDate_FromDate(int(year_month_day.year()), unsigned(year_month_day.month()), unsigned(year_month_day.day()));
}

This worked well when passing to/returning from the C++ code a single datetime.date. However I was getting type errors when attempting to pass a Python list of datetime.date objects to the C++ code.
Having reviewed the STL typemaps supplied by SWIG and debugging the C++ interface code produced I decided I needed to implement specialisations of the traits_asval<T>/traits_asptr<T>/traits_from<T> structs as were created when, for example, wrapping std::vector<std::pair<>> and re-wrote the interface file as follows:
%inline %{
#include "Common/Date/Date.h"
#include <datetime.h>
%}

%init %{
    PyDateTime_IMPORT;
%}

%fragment("DateTraits","header") {
namespace swig
{
    template<> struct traits_asval<Date>
    {
        static int asval(PyObject* obj, Date* date)
        {
            if (PyDate_Check(obj))
            {
                *date = SCI::SEQUAL::DATE::Date(std::chrono::sys_days(std::chrono::year_month_day(std::chrono::year(PyDateTime_GET_YEAR(obj)), std::chrono::month(PyDateTime_GET_MONTH(obj)), std::chrono::day(PyDateTime_GET_DAY(obj)))));

                return SWIG_OK;
            }
            else return SWIG_ERROR;
        }
    };

    template<> struct traits_asptr<Date>
    {
        static int asptr(PyObject *obj, Date** date)
        {
          *date = new Date(std::chrono::sys_days(std::chrono::year_month_day(std::chrono::year(PyDateTime_GET_YEAR(obj)), std::chrono::month(PyDateTime_GET_MONTH(obj)), std::chrono::day(PyDateTime_GET_DAY(obj)))));

          return SWIG_OK;
        }
    };

    template<> struct traits_from<Date>
    {
        static PyObject* from(const Date& val)
        {
            auto year_month_day(val.year_month_day());

            return PyDate_FromDate(int(year_month_day.year()), unsigned(year_month_day.month()), unsigned(year_month_day.day()));
        }
    };
}
}

namespace DATE
{
%typemap(in, fragment="DateTraits") Date {
    swig::traits_asval<Date>::asval($input, &$1);
}

%typemap(out, fragment="DateTraits") Date {
    $result = swig::traits_from<Date>::from($1);
}
}

This appears to work, I can now pass lists of datetime.date to functions taking std::vector<Date>, however the code path used is the traits_asptr one, which results in allocating memory for each element in the input list. I would prefer the code to use the traits_asval code path, as is done for say std::vector<std::string> but cannot figure out how to make this happen.
I have tried to add the following to the interface file:
template <> struct traits< Date > {
    typedef value_category category;
    static const char* type_name() { return "Date"; }
  };

But this simply causes a compilation failure as there are now two definitions for struct traits< Date > one defining category as value_category and one as pointer_category .
I'm hoping someone can provide me some pointers as to how I can persuade SWIG to treat my Date class as a value rather than pointer type when performing these conversions?

I've figured this out. Will post the solution here in case anyone is interested
